# CSS :not pseudo-class not working as expected in IE9

Tags: css

Unfortunately, I'm stuck working with legacy code in IE9.

Long story short, I'm cloning an itinerary template (hidden) using jQuery and applying a top border to all clones *except* the first visible (which is really the second *actual* because the template is hidden).

What I'm running into is that the border renders in Chrome, FF, and Opera, but not IE9. I *think* it's because I'm stringing several pseudo-classes together, though in my mind that shouldn't cause a problem.

I'm targeting the itineraries as follows:

```
  #itinerary table.formTable:not(:nth-child(2)):after {
    content: "";
    border-top: 1px solid #999999;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -130px;
    margin-left: 17px;
    display: block;
  }
```

Basically, apply the above CSS to all except the second itinerary.

The qusetion is, why is this happening in IE9? According to [can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anot), the pseudo-class is suported. Is this becuse I've strung so many into this particular rule? I'm at a loss.

Here's how it's supposed to look (Chrome):

[image]

Here's what's going on in IE9:

[image]

Here's a close-up of the CSS from the IE9 screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't `:after` have a double colon? (`::after`)  Try it like that instead.

Comment: @RBarryYoung `:after` is also allowed because of backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Oriol Yes, but support for it may not be consistent.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? I can't reproduce on IE 11 in IE 9 mode.

Answer (score 1):

Extended arguments are not supported in IE9 for the pseudo-class :not

[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) are the docs on that issue

Most likely you can use

```
 #itinerary table.formTable:not(:nth-child(2))
```

but not

```
 #itinerary table.formTable:not(:nth-child(2)):after
```

Fortunately IE9 supports [conditional commenting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx) so you can write a fallback for IE9 and >

Comment: Thanks for the input, @HelloWorld. Unfortunately  #itinerary table.formTable:not(:nth-child(2)) didn't work. I tried to simplify it further with: #itinerary table.formTable:after but with no luck. Hmm...

Comment: @scott try working backward from #itinerary table.formTable:not(:last-child) to #itinerary table.formTable:not(#some_id) and #itinerary table.formTable:not(some_element). The docs say that "basic support" is provided for ":not" and that "extended arguments" (which seems broad to me) are not supported at all.

Comment: OK. Good suggestion. I was wondering about extended arguments too. The docs suggest they're not supported in Chrome, FF, Opera, etc. either, but they work none the less. Guess I need to research "extended arguments." :) Thanks!

Comment: "Extended arguments" means that [Selectors L3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-3/#negation) only allows a [simple selector](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-3/#simple-selectors-dfn) as the argument of `:not`, but [Selectors L4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#negation) allows any [selector list](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#selector-list). Since `:nth-child` is a pseudo-class, and thus a simple selector, this not not the problem.